# Solving $x + \sqrt[3]{x} = 30$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $x + \sqrt[3]{x} = 30$, then what is the value of $x$?

Please help me!
Thank you.

Comment: Isn't one value obvious to you? (x =27)? For others try converting it to a cubic equation.

Comment: Once you notice that $x=27$ is a solution, notice that $x$ is a monotonically increasing function, and $x^{1/3}$ also is monotonic, so $x+x^{1/3}$ as a whole is monotonic.

Answer (score 7):

Hint: 
Let $t=\sqrt[3]x$ and note that $$t^3+t-30=(t-3)(t^2+3t+10).$$

Answer (score 4):

hint:

$x^{1/3}=30-x$ can nicely be written if you raise both sides to the power of three.